# How to installation Together2008r3 for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins

How can i installation together2008r3 in Eclipse, Dose anybody could help me?

I've download the Together2008r3.zip right now.

first, I install Eclipse SKD in Eclipse and restart. 
the second, I click Help-Install new software in Eclipse and choose the zip file then click continue.
but it's back an error.

> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
>     Software being installed: Together Classic Modeling (required) 8.2.3.v20101117-1439 (com.borland.together.classic.feature.group 8.2.3.v20101117-1439)
>     Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
>       EMF Change Model 2.5.1.v20100907-1643 (org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change 2.5.1.v20100907-1643)
>       EMF Change Model 2.7.0.v20110408-2116 (org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change 2.7.0.v20110408-2116)
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Together OCL Modeling UI 8.2.3.v20101117-1439 (com.borland.tg.modeling.ocl.ui.feature.group 8.2.3.v20101117-1439)
>       To: org.eclipse.emf.all.feature.group [2.6.0,3.0.0)
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Together Classic Modeling (required) 8.2.3.v20101117-1439 (com.borland.together.classic.feature.group 8.2.3.v20101117-1439)
>       To: com.borland.together.feature.group [8.2.3.v20101117-1439]
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Together Modeling 8.2.3.v20101117-1439 (com.borland.together.feature.group 8.2.3.v20101117-1439)
>       To: com.borland.tg.modeling.ocl.ui.feature.group [8.2.3.v20101117-1439]
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: EMF/XSD All-In-One SDK 2.6.0.v20100914-1218 (org.eclipse.emf.all.feature.group 2.6.0.v20100914-1218)
>       To: org.eclipse.emf.sdk.feature.group [2.6.1.v20100914-1218]
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: EMF Change Edit 2.5.0.v20100521-1846 (org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change.edit 2.5.0.v20100521-1846)
>       To: bundle org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change [2.7.0,3.0.0)
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: EMF - Eclipse Modeling Framework SDK 2.6.1.v20100914-1218 (org.eclipse.emf.sdk.feature.group 2.6.1.v20100914-1218)
>       To: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change [2.5.1.v20100907-1643]
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: EMF - Eclipse Modeling Framework SDK 2.6.1.v20100914-1218 (org.eclipse.emf.sdk.feature.group 2.6.1.v20100914-1218)
>       To: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change.edit [2.5.0.v20100521-1846]

I just know something dependency lib was not found. it's because I used the J2EE edition for Eclipse(not classic)?

Answer (score 1):

From what i see, it's because you have Version 2.5.1 of EMF Change Model installed, but ToGether needs 2.7.1 and the automatic installation wizard cannot resolve this.
Which version of Eclipse do you use? I think, the Indigo packages contain EMF 2.7, so with Eclipse Indigo, it should work. Otherwise you would have to uninstall EMF and manually install a newer EMF version (for information and download sites etc. [look here](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/updates/)).

Comment: Thank you and My Eclipse Version is:  Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers. Version: 1.4.0.20110615-0550
Build id: 20110615-0604 > so you means i need download a latest Eclipse or update EMF lib?

Comment: Actually i think, i misunderstood the error message. Your Eclipse Version seems to be the latest (since it's from June 2011, which is Indigo). And it seems, that you have the newest EMF Version, but Together needs an older versions (since it's the 2008 release, that seems to be plausible).

Comment: what is so bad message >_< I will download a old version and hava a try. But anyway, Thanks a lot.